# JavaScript OOP vs Non OOP memory usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory, memory-management

I have a API written in NodeJs and I have used a class as the controller. The code looks something similar to this.

```
 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    new TestController().getData(req, res);
 });
```

Here the TestController class is a big one with a lot of functions. And  `getData()` doesn't use any class variables. So I can get rid of the class and call the function directly as follows.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    getData(req, res);
});
```

Or I can make the function static too.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    TestController.getData(req, res);
});
```

Is there any memory usage difference in these three approaches, if the load to API is very high?

Comment: There are no real differences between the last two. The `new TestController` approach obviously allocates more memory, and can have arbitrarily large overhead, depending on what the constructor does.

Comment: Yes, your initial version is a bit wastful here, but there should be very little difference using a class static & a simple function.

Comment: So not only in this example, if I use classes unnecessarily it will be using unnecessary memory, won't it?

Comment: It all depends really, eg, say you had a `Point` class, it's an ideal candidate for a `class`, extracting into `object` and using helper functions, really wouldn't gain you anything memory wise, but you would loose a bit on code readability.